# How can I correctly catch-all subdomains (and redirect) with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, catch-all

I have wild card subdomains (*.domain.com) set up on my server. I now would like to use .htaccess to redirect all *.domain.com requests to a script main.php on my server. I searched for code that would help accomplish the redirect but I have not been entirely successful. The best working code I have found is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

However, www.subdomain.domain.com is redirected to domain.com/www.subdomain instead of domain.com/subdomain. How can this be fixed in the code? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @tundoopani: In a URL like this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` REQUEST_URI is `questions` and HTTP_HOST is `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Is there a way to make the www. optional?

Comment: @tundoopani: I edited my answer to make www. optional, please see above.